# Role added to HttpContext.current.user but isInRole(rolename) is not working

Tags: c#, forms-authentication

Here is my code about Authentication and Authorization

```html
public class SessionContext
{
    public void setAuthenticationToken(UserAccount userAccount,bool isPersistant,string name)
    {
        string data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(userAccount.Roles);
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,name,DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),isPersistant,data);
        var encryptedCookieData = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie httpCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedCookieData) { HttpOnly=true,Expires=ticket.Expiration };
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
    }
}
```

My Global.asax has this method:

```html
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        
        string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
        
        GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), roles);
        
        HttpContext.Current.User = userPrincipal;
        
        Debug.WriteLine(roles.FirstOrDefault() +" "+ userPrincipal.IsInRole("Admin"));
    }
}
```

But when I using **[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]** authorizing not working.

I tried these solutions but didn't work:

1. I used **[CustomAthorize(Roles="Admin")]** that explained in StackOverflow
2. I used **Thread.CurrentPrincipal=userPrincipal**

**Notice:** As you can see I added Debug.WriteLine() in my Global.asax to show me userPrincipal role state but always returns false.

**Notice:** If you can , show me another way to use Authorization and Authentication that not based on OWIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the problem is in saving role name to HttpContext it was saving role name with "" in while it have to save without ""